# Python: boto3 decrypt

Tags: encryption, boto3, amazon-kms

I'm trying to decrypt via the boto3 a ecrypted value with kms.

The value is encrypted via the aws cli and then stored:

```
aws kms encrypt --key-id xxx --plaintext "test"
```

The code that I'm trying to use to decrypt then is following:

```
    kms_response = kms.decrypt(
        CiphertextBlob = token
    )
    runner_token = kms_response['Plaintext']
```

The answer is unfortunately like this **b'\cf6\pec-'**.
I'm tried to add following **kms_response['Plaintext'].decode(**) to my script, but I get following error:

```
{
  "errorMessage": "'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xb1 in position 0: invalid start byte",
  "errorType": "UnicodeDecodeError",
  "stackTrace": [
    "  File \"/var/task/terminate_hook.py\", line 32, in lambda_handler\n    runner_token = kms_response['Plaintext'].decode()\n"
  ]
}
```

Has anyone an idea why this isn't working?

Thanks,
Yannick